# Stuck on early example with Celery, Anaconda, RabbitMQ

Tags: python, celery, anaconda

I have a large number of computations in .py scripts that i want to automate. Since Celery support dependency it seems like the perfect fit. However I get stuck in the very first example in "First Steps with Celery".

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

This code gives me this error

```
ImportError: cannot import name Celery
```

Im running a windows machine.

I have used anaconda to install python

I use RabbitMQ

I have installed Erlang

I used pip to inststall Celery

Comment: It seems that it depends on which folder i run my code from. For example if i execute ipython notebook from its default location everything works but if i try in some other location i can not import Celery...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have multiples version of Python and that the one that pip used is not the same as the one Anaconda installed ?